# Merging on DatetimeIndexes and on = ''

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, merge

I have two [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) data frames, that I need to merge on both indexes and one other variables.  Like this,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 9
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
      "ctr": np.repeat(['India', 'Indonesia', 'Italy'],n),
      "group": np.resize([10,10,10,200,200,200,300,300,300],n*3),
      "num": list(range(0,n*3))
                 })
index1 = pd.DatetimeIndex(np.tile(pd.date_range(start='31/12/2021', periods=3, freq='Q'), 9))
df1.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(index1)
df1
                  ctr  group  num
2021-12-31      India     10    0
2022-03-31      India     10    1
2022-06-30      India     10    2
2021-12-31      India    200    3
2022-03-31      India    200    4
2022-06-30      India    200    5
2021-12-31      India    300    6
2022-03-31      India    300    7
2022-06-30      India    300    8
2021-12-31  Indonesia     10    9
2022-03-31  Indonesia     10   10
2022-06-30  Indonesia     10   11
2021-12-31  Indonesia    200   12
2022-03-31  Indonesia    200   13
2022-06-30  Indonesia    200   14
2021-12-31  Indonesia    300   15
2022-03-31  Indonesia    300   16
2022-06-30  Indonesia    300   17
2021-12-31      Italy     10   18
2022-03-31      Italy     10   19
2022-06-30      Italy     10   20
2021-12-31      Italy    200   21
2022-03-31      Italy    200   22
2022-06-30      Italy    200   23
2021-12-31      Italy    300   24
2022-03-31      Italy    300   25
2022-06-30      Italy    300   26

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
      "group": [10,10,200,200,300,300],
      "num2": list(range(n*3,n*3+6))
                })
index2 = pd.DatetimeIndex(np.tile(pd.date_range(start='31/3/2022', periods=2, freq='Q'), 3))
df2.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(index2)
df2
            group  num2
2022-03-31     10    27
2022-06-30     10    28
2022-03-31    200    29
2022-06-30    200    30
2022-03-31    300    31
2022-06-30    300    32
```

Now I've come as far as this,

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True, on = 'group')
```

but it doesn't give what I'm looking for. What I would like to obtain is something like this where `df2` is repeated for each country in `df1`, like this. Is that possible?

```
                  ctr  group  num  num2
2021-12-31      India     10    0     
2022-03-31      India     10    1    27
2022-06-30      India     10    2    28
2021-12-31      India    200    3      
2022-03-31      India    200    4    29
2022-06-30      India    200    5    30
2021-12-31      India    300    6    
2022-03-31      India    300    7    31
2022-06-30      India    300    8    32
2021-12-31  Indonesia     10    9     
2022-03-31  Indonesia     10   10    27
2022-06-30  Indonesia     10   11    28
2021-12-31  Indonesia    200   12    
2022-03-31  Indonesia    200   13    29
2022-06-30  Indonesia    200   14    30
2021-12-31  Indonesia    300   15     
2022-03-31  Indonesia    300   16    31
2022-06-30  Indonesia    300   17    32
2021-12-31      Italy     10   18     
2022-03-31      Italy     10   19    27
2022-06-30      Italy     10   20    28
2021-12-31      Italy    200   21    
2022-03-31      Italy    200   22    29
2022-06-30      Italy    200   23    30
2021-12-31      Italy    300   24     
2022-03-31      Italy    300   25    31
2022-06-30      Italy    300   26    32
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
x = (
    pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), how="outer", on=["index", "group"])
    .sort_values(by=["ctr", "group"])
    .set_index("index")
    .fillna("")
    .rename_axis(None)
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
                  ctr  group  num  num2
2021-12-31      India     10    0      
2022-03-31      India     10    1  27.0
2022-06-30      India     10    2  28.0
2021-12-31      India    200    3      
2022-03-31      India    200    4  29.0
2022-06-30      India    200    5  30.0
2021-12-31      India    300    6      
2022-03-31      India    300    7  31.0
2022-06-30      India    300    8  32.0
2021-12-31  Indonesia     10    9      
2022-03-31  Indonesia     10   10  27.0
2022-06-30  Indonesia     10   11  28.0
2021-12-31  Indonesia    200   12      
2022-03-31  Indonesia    200   13  29.0
2022-06-30  Indonesia    200   14  30.0
2021-12-31  Indonesia    300   15      
2022-03-31  Indonesia    300   16  31.0
2022-06-30  Indonesia    300   17  32.0
2021-12-31      Italy     10   18      
2022-03-31      Italy     10   19  27.0
2022-06-30      Italy     10   20  28.0
2021-12-31      Italy    200   21      
2022-03-31      Italy    200   22  29.0
2022-06-30      Italy    200   23  30.0
2021-12-31      Italy    300   24      
2022-03-31      Italy    300   25  31.0
2022-06-30      Italy    300   26  32.0
```